# Manga in which the main character has an adopted sister who is preferred over her due to her beauty

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character was reincarnated into the world of a book she read. In this world, she had a sister and they lived with their parents. The main character was the biological daughter while her sister was adopted. The adopted sister was preferred because of her beauty.

I think the sister gets hurt or something. Then they go to this school, where all the male leads are obsessed with the sister, but the main character already knew about this, because she read the book. So as she tried to get them to back off, the male leads actually started liking the main character, rather than her sister.

I think the main character has red hair, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?